# jquery - why does not :checkbox:checked validation not work

Tags: jquery, validation

I am working on an application for a client.  Will require special validation coding, so I CAN'T use a plugin as I have in several other apps.  I had this code working when validating text an dropdown fields, but it broke when I added the code to validate checkboxes.  What am I do wrong in this jquery code? **my jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/7N7bw/

**complete jquery code:>>**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function(){
        $("#holdErrMsg").empty();
        var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[type="text"][class*="-required"],textarea[class*="-required"],select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
            });
        var chkbx_reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[type="checkbox"][class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    return !$(this).is(':checked')
            });
                    var holdAll = reqButEmpty + chkbx_reqButEmpty;
                    if(holdAll.length > 0)
                        {
                            holdAll.each(function() {
                                $('#holdErrMsg').append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />"); 
                            });
                        }
                    return !holdAll.length;
                });
        });
```

**Above was working until I added this checkbox validation: >>**

```
var chkbx_reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[type="checkbox"][class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    return !$(this).is(':checked')
            });
                    var holdAll = reqButEmpty + chkbx_reqButEmpty;
```

**Here is the jquery with the new suggestions - but does not work>>**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function(){
        $("#holdErrMsg").empty();
        var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[type="text"][class*="-required"],textarea[class*="-required"],select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
            });
        //var chkbx_reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[type="checkbox"][class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
        var chkbx_reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input:checked[class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    console.log(this);
                    //return !$(this).is(':checked')
                    //return !this.checked;
                    return $(this).is(!':checked');
            });
                    //var holdAll = reqButEmpty + chkbx_reqButEmpty;
                    //var holdAll = reqButEmpty.concat(chkbx_reqButEmpty).length;
                    var holdAll = $.extend(reqButEmpty,chkbx_reqButEmpty);
                    if(holdAll.length > 0)
                        {
                            holdAll.each(function() {
                                $('#holdErrMsg').append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />"); 
                            });
                        }
                    return !holdAll.length;
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `(input:checked)` in your find function ?

```
$('fieldset:visible').find('input:checked[class*="-required"]').filter(function(){});
```

edit :

shouldn't this line : `return !$(this).is(':checked')`
be `return $(this).is(':checked')`

Edit :

```
if(!$(this)is(':checked')
    return true/false;
```

Comment: Now I get this error [Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object][object Object] has no method 'each'], but I am not using .each because the is() should check to see if any of the boxes are checked.

Comment: I want to get catch the fields that are required, but not filled-in, so in this case it should be not is check

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return $(this).is(!':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in line:

```
var holdAll = reqButEmpty + chkbx_reqButEmpty;
```

By concatenating two JQuery objects you get type `[Object][Object]`.

Use this code instead:

```
var holdAll = $.extend(reqButEmpty,chkbx_reqButEmpty);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7N7bw/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var chkbx_reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[type="checkbox"][class*="-required"]').filter(function() {
      return !this.checked;
});
var holdAll = reqButEmpty.concat(chkbx_reqButEmpty).length;
```